# Выдает ошибку ,не могу способ найти ,как исправить

Tags: 1с

ошибка ссылается на модуль `РаботаСоСправочниками.РозничнаяЦена`, в самом модуле

```
&НаКлиенте
Функция  РозничнаяЦена(АктуальнаяДата,ЭлементНоменклатуры) Экспорт
    
Отбор = Новый Структура("Номенклатура",ЭлементНоменклатуры);
ЗначенияРесурсов = РегистрыСведений.Цены.ПолучитьПоследнее(АктуальнаяДата,Отбор);
Возврат ЗначенияРесурсов.Цена;
ти способ как
КонецФункции
```

[image]

Comment: Черным по белому написано, что не определили переменную

Comment: я понятие не имею какую переменную ставитб

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqxY2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&НаКлиенте` нельзя обращаться к регистрам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рекомендую изучить:

1. [Как работает серверный вызов в 1С](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/682305/)
2. [Основные понятия и механизмы оптимизации клиент-серверного взаимодействия в 1C](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/891857/)

Comment: как на моем примере переписать код?

Comment: @12121212, разобрались?